# How should I organize making a cake days ahead?

Tags: baking, cake, cream, organization, mousse

My wife's birthday is coming up and I want to make a cake for her.

I was thinking of making a layer of sponge cake, amarena cherry sauce (cherries, wine and sugar), chocolate mousse, another layer of sponge cake with sauce, Diplomat cream and amarena cherries on top.

The problem is that I won't have time the day we eat the cake (Saturday) and the day before (Friday), so I need to make it in advance. I'm thinking of preparing the sponge cake, cherry sauce and chocolate mousse on Thursday and build the bottom layers and put it in the freezer. I can make the Diplomat cream on Friday morning, save it in the refrigerator, and build the rest on Saturday (after we'll arrive home).

Does this sounds like a good plan? is it better to just make the pastry cream on Friday and mixed it with the whipped cream on Saturday? Can the cake and the mousse wait for two days?

Comment: I edited your question quite a bit. We only answer constructive questions. The part where you asked our opinion (if this cake would be good enough), can't be answered objectively. You can ask another question if there is something not clear in the recipe you chose. I changed your second question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my previous comment: if you aren't sure of your choice of cake, feel free to discuss it in our chat room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't make the layers fully in the freezer.  It will be hard to seal up and may dry out.  Also, frozen layers are easier to work with.  The freezer will dry out unsealed cake extremely fast.

I'd bake all the cake, trim and level them, wrap **tightly** and freeze on Thursday.  Make the sauces and creams on Friday and put them in the fridge.  Assemble all on Saturday.

Comment: I think cherry sauce can be prepared on Thursday without a problem, just like the chocolate mousse (when prepared correctly) and kept in the fridge (I don't know how much time the OP has on Friday morning).

Comment: @Mien You certainly could, I just trying to make it as close to time as possible to extend the shelf life for leftovers.  If the OP is planning on having no leftover cake, then make it anytime in the 3-5 days beforehand.

Comment: @rfusca Hi,Thank you both for your replies. I don't have much time on Friday.
It seems to me that all can be prepared on Thursday except for the cream.
I still have two Dillemas: saving the cake and moussse separated from each other or built in layers and if it's better to save the cream before adding the whipped cream (and add it on Saturday) or after

Comment: @yuchtman I'd save them seperate from each other, unless you think you can sufficiently wrap stacked cakes *tightly* for the freezer (I'm not sure how you could accomplish that without squeezing out the mousse).  As far as the dipolmat cream - if you're doing it with a thickener like gelatin, it should be fine to make ahead.